# How to install components and set search path in Delphi 10.3?

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm a newbie, trying to install the [Drag and Drop Component Suite](https://github.com/landrix/The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi) into the Delphi Community Edition. Here's what I did:

1. I cloned the repository.
2. As instructed, in the Packages folder, I found the design time package for Delphi 10.3, opened it in Delphi, compiled and then installed the resulting file.

The new components show up on my component palette. I can drop them onto another project. However, if I compile the project I get a message saying the DragDrop unit's not found.The author's directions for installing the unit include "Locate the Library sub-folder that matches your version of Delphi. Add it to the Delphi library search path."

This is clearly the issue and also the part of the process I don't know how to do, it would seem. In addition, after compiling and installing the Drag and Drop Component Suite, when I look in the component's source folder the `Library` sub-folder (which was part of the original repository) is empty. (Did I compile the source correctly? Should there be files created in the `Library` folder after compiling?)

Comment: The community edition is 10.3, not 10.4

Comment: @Renate Good catch; thank you. I edited my text to say 10.3.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I edited the text to be less redundant; thank you. I think I was caught up in trying to be specific because, looking on my own, it seems procedures for adding files to Delphi search paths differ (significantly?) for older and newer versions.

Comment: No, not really, it's almost the same procedure for every version. In newer versions (that is about since XE2 or so) you have to choose the compiler target (32/64 Bit Windows, Android etc.) for which you want to add a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate the folder "Source" and add the complete path to Delphi library path.

You'll find Delphi Library path using:
Menu /Tools / Options / Language / Delphi / Library / Library Path
Click on the 3 dots on the right to manage the list.